# localStorage and local files

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, local-storage

We are planning to create a image manipulation service in HTML5. One goal is that the service would work for anonymous users.

- User adds a image (open file dialog / drag and drop)
- User manipulates image in the browser
- User saves the result

Now, the trick here is that the browser may die under us on any moment (user exists, laptop battery is empty, etc...) We'd like to have some kind of auto-save here which records the progress. This means keeping the track of images added on the page, preferably in offline manner.

The question is, can we somehow locally auto-save files and images user has added on the page, or are we forced to make user re-enter all images he/she has added on the page in the case page must be reloaded? Does localStorage has support for local file objects or references?

Comment: Did you consider cookies? Local storage survives a page refresh...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can implement auto-save feature.

You might use HTML5 Canvas API to let users to manipulate image in the browser. Then you can use [toDataURL](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-todataurl) method to get the data URL of the image. After get that, you can save it to localstorage. We can save just strings in localstorage for now. [Spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/) says object can be saved in localstorage but most browsers don't support it.

The `setInterval` method can be used to save the image periodically.

Comment: The problem is that dataURIs yield to considerable big images with photos. E.g. 1920 x 1080 full HD photo as PNG image would be several megabytes. I don't think localStorage allows even megabytes to be stored.

Comment: You can use five megabytes. I think it's enough for a image. http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/#disk-space

Comment: But not enough for several images :(

Comment: Looks like image/jpeg encoding for dataURI is coming on *some* browsers which would make using storage little bit more sensible

Comment: You can ask for ulimited storage if you publish it as a chrome extension. Otherwise you will be limited to 5 MB.

http://code.google.com/chrome/extensions/manifest.html#permissions

Answer (score 1):

Not possible:

http://dev.w3.org/2006/webapi/FileAPI/#lifeTime

Comment: The data URL is different from Blob URI.

Comment: As stated above, dataURIs for photos are too big to fit to localStorage